# Script-based filtered query-based that fetch data from another sheet based on listed entries

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a problem where I have two sheets. one sheet is the [source spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19FkL3rsh5sxdujb6x00BUPvXEEhiXfAeURTeQi3YWzo/edit?usp=sharing) and another is a [target spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AThfeK1gWEbV7qiM4CLTszd-T170tn4kTfybW6fcZN0/edit?usp=sharing). The source spreadsheet has a source sheet has which is the master database and the target spreadsheet has the target where we want to fetch data from source sheet based on emails provided in the Emails tab in the target spreadsheet.

I want the following things to happen with a script and not with IMPORTRANGE or QUERY:

- The target spreadsheet will have multiple copies so I want to connect the target spreadsheet with the source spreadsheet based on the source spreadsheet's id.
- I want the email matches to be case insensitive so that the users of the target spreadsheet can type emails in any case.
- The Emails can go up to 50 or let's say get the last row for that column.
- It will be great if the script shows a pop up saying updated after it has fetched the data.
- The source sheet might have data up to 15000 rows so I am thinking about speed too.

I have shared both of the spreadsheets with hyperlinks to their names. I am not really great at scripts so it will be helpful if you can leave comments in it wherever you feel like. I would truly appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance!
Edit: I am updating my broken script here:

```js
function fetch() {
  //get the sheets
  var source_Ssheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('19FkL3rsh5sxdujb6x00BUPvXEEhiXfAeURTeQi3YWzo');
  var target_Ssheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  //get the tabs
  var email_sheet = target_Ssheet.getSheetByName("Emails");
  var target_sheet = target_Ssheet.getSheetByName("Target Sheet");
  var source_sheet = source_Ssheet.getSheetByName("Source Sheet");

  //get ranges
  var email_list = email_sheet.getRange("B2:B");
  var target_sheet_range = target_sheet.getRange("A1:F100");
  var source_sheet_range = source_sheet.getRange("A1:F100");
  
  //get last rows
  var last_email_name = email_list.getLastRow();
  var last_target_sheet_range = target_sheet_range.getLastRow();
  var last_source_sheet_range = source_sheet_range.getLastRow();

  //start searching for emails
  for (var i=3; i < last_email_name.length+1; i++)
  {
    for(varj=3; j< last_source_sheet_range.length+1; j++ )
    {
        if(source_sheet_range[j][3].getValue() == email_list[i][3].getValue())
        {
          //copy matches to target sheet
          target_sheet.getRange((last_target_sheet_range + 1),1,1,10).setValues(master_sheet_range[j].getValues()); 
        }
        
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Several thoughts.  First, this feels like you are asking for the people on SO to help develop your application for you - but you haven't shown any steps you've taken to try to achieve this.  Is the reason requiring a GAS Script primarily for performance?  Second, to clarify - in your target sheet in the Emails tab, is this where users will type in a list of email addresses (up to 50?), and you want all of the associated data from the source sheet returned into the "Target Sheet" tab?

Comment: Hi Krikg13,

Yes, you are correct on that part that it seems like I am asking people to develop it. But I have tried making script on my working sheets which I can't share here so I have made new demo sheets here. I could remake my broken script but with my limited experience with google scripts that won't add any real value to anyone here. Basically, I was trying to make a nested loop where for each email id from target sheet. It will check against all the email ids in source sheet and return the row when its a match. It will take the next email form Emails sheet. both loops till last row.

Comment: Continued comment for you @kirkg13 ...
Yes, I am concerned about the performance and also I intend to keep multiple target sheets so doesn't want to go into the permission thing with importrange function. I also afraid for the loop to take long time when the database will be like 15000 rows. What are your thoughts on that? I am open to explore other solutions.

Finally, Yes, you have got that part absolutely right where I want emails from emails tab to match from source sheet and return the match row to "Target Sheet"